# Replace numeric axis with datetime axis in broken_barh

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axes

All,

I'm comparing a few time series using matplotlib's `broken_barh` command---it's a nice way to compare data gaps in multiple, simultaneous, time series. Because `broken_barh` appears to only take numerical input, I'm using POSIX times.

Once finished, I would like to change the x-axis to display nicely formatted dates and times.

Now, I can do this directly through something like:

```py
xtick_locations = ax.xaxis.get_majorticklocs()
xtick_new_labels = [
    '{0:04n}-{1:02n}-{2:02n}\n{3:02n}:{4:02n}:{5:02n}'.format(
    t.year,t.month,t.day,t.hour,t.minute,t.second) for t in
    [pd.Timestamp(tick,unit='s') for tick in xtick_locations]]
plt.xticks(xticks_locations,xtick_new_labels,rotation='vertical')
```

But then my times and dates are not located at nice, logical locations, e.g. the start of days, weeks, months, and so forth as dependent upon the plotted range.

Does anyone know a way to use `matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator` and `matplotlib.dates.AutoDateFormatter` to intelligently calculate and display new tick locations given my original, numerical x-axis? Can I suppress the original axis and overlay it with a new one?

Thanks!